# How to groupby after partitioning in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a series of a graph edges in the format of `src_node dst_node edge_weigth`. I want to to read them from a `.txt` file and then use them for some algorithms. But before applying the algorithms, I need to clean up and group the data. Also I want to use only `RDD`'s.

The problem with the the input data is that it has loops, first I want to filter the loops out and then re-partition the RDD to 8 partitions. However want to have access to each nodes outgoing edges etc, so for each node I need to store set of `(dst,weight)`s. Also I want to have a good performance(I'm afraid that a repatriation and a groupby will cause two shuffles)

I have came-up with this code until now but I don't know how to finish it :

```
links = sc.textFile("./inputs/graph1.txt") \
    .map(lambda link: links.split(" "))\
    .filter(lambda link: link[0] != link[1])
```

This is a sample input data:

```
1 2 5
1 3 2
1 1 2
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 4
```

What should I do?

Comment: So, what is your expected output?

Comment: something like: `src_nod => [(dst_node1,weight1),(dst_node2,weight2),...]` for each node

Comment: `links.map(lambda link: link.split(" ")).filter(lambda link: link[0] != link[1]).map(lambda link: (link[0], (link[1], link[2]))).groupByKey(8)` is slow?

Comment: tnx, just can you explain what is the difference between `reparation(8).groupByKey()` and `.groupByKey(8)`?

Comment: You can check the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/rdd.html#RDD.groupByKey). By default, the number of partition of `groupByKey` is `spark.default.parallelism`; if it is unset, it equals to the number of partition of the parent RDD.